# Autowiring in Spring 3 MDP

Tags: spring

Firstly I've checked some of the possible answers that come up when posting a new question and none that I have come across deals with my issue.

I have a Spring MDP which works nicely i.e. can receive messages. The problem is when I try to autowire a dependency, the autowiring doesn't seem to work. I'm using Netbeans and Glassfish 3.1.2 so I'm able to step through the code and can confirm that the dependencies are null. Autowiring in other parts of the application are working fine. The MDP is picked up in the component-scan.

I used the example from springsource to create my MDP:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

And I've autowired the dependencies by setter methods.

I cannot figure out why this won't work. I've checked around and I don't think anyone else has had this issue.

Any ideas, pointers in the right direction, examples I can reference will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

KSS

MDP Class:

```
public class ExampleListener implements MessageListener {

    private Transformer transformer;
    private MurexService murexService;

    @Autowired
    public void setTransformer(Transformer transformer) {
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMurexService(MurexService murexService) {
        this.murexService = murexService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

ApplicationContext:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="jms/QueueConnectionFactory" />  
<jee:jndi-lookup id="testQueueOne" jndi-name="jms/ITFS_RECEIVE" /> 

<!-- this is the Message Driven POJO (MDP) -->
<bean id="messageListener" class="com.scm.service.ExampleListener" />


<!-- and this is the message listener container -->
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="testQueueOne"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```

Comment: It would help if you included the code that you've written.

Comment: Apologies. I should have added that in.

Comment: Hi Eivind. I've editted my post and added the MDP class and part of the applicationContext. If there is any more code that I should post pls let me know. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) needs to be registered for wiring in the @Autowired fields. The javadoc has more details. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16149214/204788) for the solution to a similar issue.

Essentially adding this should get the autowiring to work:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: Biju, I've read through your comments on your solution to the similar issue. That reminded me about the different contexts at work. So I added the jndi lookups and the bean definitions xml code to the dispatcher-servlet and that solved the problem. I think I need to refresh my memory and read more on the contexts. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated :-)

Comment: Apologies Biju, I cannot vote this up. I don't have 15 reputation points yet.

Comment: This is the problem with annotations in general, you still need to turn them all on, hence why I prefer to just do it all in xml :)

Comment: Good point. Afaik one may use xml and annotations together. So I wonder why the Spring guys made that optional. That should be turned-on as the default.